# How do I get Gmail to stop "detecting suspicious activity" every time I travel?

Tags: gmail, security

Every time I travel, Gmail believes there may be suspicious activity as the sign in comes from a different location; I get that.

However, it then asks for my password and usually will not recognize it.  So, I can’t access my email account.

Any way to prevent this?

Comment: What is the exact error message you receive, both when it informs you of suspicious activity and when Gmail won't accept your password? Gmail should still recognize your password if you're traveling.

Comment: Also, have you disabled the alert within Gmail by clicking "Details" at the bottom of Gmail (to bring up the list of IP addresses that have visited your account), clicking "Change", then clicking "Never show an alert for unusual activity". After disabling that, do you still get locked out when traveling?

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent this by:

1. Using Gmail web main interface on the same computer device (as Gmail would probably use the cookies or any other information related to your computer);
2. setting up your Gmail account as internal email account (either POP3 or IMAP) in the Mail program of your computer;
3. using Gmail App for smart phones or a tablet version (or any 3rd party application synchronised with Gmail).

I think those are the ways that would allow you to avoid this annoying security checks. I hope that the options listed above will help.

Comment: Point 1 is not true.  Even on the same computer, in the same location, it goes nuts.  Maybe the cookies  are expiring after first use (and not refreshing from continuous use)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no, there is no way to disable that. Using POP3 or IMAP to access your account does not stop the IP region check, there is no way to do it -- I have tried for years and of course Google does not answer emails.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the account via VPN or public/private proxy. That should prevent this from happening. At least it has been helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

A possible option is to redirect inbox to other mail service (ProtonMail, Tutanota, etc.) (temporarily for the travel or even permanently) and to answer from it.
Some of these secure mail services are supposed to be used from VPN and don't have concept of safe location.
This is especially helpful because you don't need to compromise your main account login from unsafe places.